# Segmentation fault in a python with queue and mutithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, segmentation-fault

I'm having `Segmentation fault` in a python program and can't figure out what is causing it:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffebfff700 (LWP 13584)]
0x00007ffff2e73492 in flag_bsearch(unsigned short*, unsigned short, int) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhunspell-1.3.so.0
```

What I'm doing basically is filling the queue of some worker threads that will process the jobs at their speed as follows (here is [link for complete code](https://github.com/dzlab/sentimentpy/blob/master/core/analyze.py#l46-l51)):

```
for worker in self.workers:
    # if worker's queue is full block otherwise enqueue without blocking
    if worker.comments_queue.full():
        worker.comments_queue.put(comment)
    else:
        worker.comments_queue.put_nowait(comment)
```

When I enable one worker I don't have this problem, the segmentation fault happens only when I enable at least two workers (here is [link for complete code](https://github.com/dzlab/sentimentpy/blob/master/core/main.py#l88-l92)):

```
analyzer = AnalyzerManager()
#analyzer.register(LengthAnalyzer())
analyzer.register(LanguageAnalyzer())
#analyzer.register(UserAnalyzer())
analyzer.register(SentimentAnalyzer())
```

Any hint to figure out what is the causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best thing to do is to look at the backtrace you're getting. It shows that the segfault is happening inside of `libhunspell.so`, which is part of the Hunspell package. That's used by the `guess_language` module. Since the segfault is happening only when multiple threads are running, it at least *appears* that hunspell is not thread-safe. So, you'll need to make sure that only one thread is accessing `guess_language` at a time. That should be easy enough with a `threading.Lock()`. I would create a helper function in your package that looks like this:

```
from guess_language import guess_language
import threading

guess_lock = threading.Lock()
def guess_language_thread_safe(text):
    with guess_lock:
        return guess_language(text)
```

And call `guess_language_thread_safe` everywhere in your code that's currently using `guess_language` directly.